# Document Listener inactive Java

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, documentlistener

I am trying to get response from ComboBox editor. So I added a `document listener` to the combobox. The problem is the document listener doesn't seem to be working at all. I think the listener is not connected to the `combobox editor`. I know I am missing something. Here is the code:

```
    // constructor of GUI class
    ComboBoxDocumentHandler handle = new ComboBoxDocumentHandler();

    JTextComponent comboEditorComponent =(JTextComponent) InstantSearchBox.getEditor().getEditorComponent();

    doc = comboEditorComponent.getDocument();

    doc.addDocumentListener(handle);

   // Document Handler class and its method
private class ComboBoxDocumentHandler implements DocumentListener
{

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Inside"); // this statement is not printing when I add something to the combobox editor
    }
}
```

Regards

Comment: probably because your code does not compile since it misses two implementing methods, one of them being: `insertUpdate()`?

Comment: I cut them out for posting the code.. My question doesn't say at all that my code doesn't compile which give the clue that required methods are implemented.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Funny how we should guess that you cut it off (you would be surprised to see how many people post questions here with code that does not compile and complain that it does not work). Even funnier that you choose that those methods are irrelevant to your problem. As Andrew said, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 3):

- all those events aren't finalized untill derived JPopup with JList is visible, and all events from Action or ItemListener are done,
- usage of derived Document make me sence for AutoComplete JComboBox (basically must contains Document and with Bias)
- example about all related Events and Listeners

Edit

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxRenderer;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

public class ComboBoxHoverOver {

    private JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();

    public ComboBoxHoverOver() {
        combo.setPrototypeDisplayValue("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        combo.setRenderer(new ComboToolTipRenderer(combo));
        combo.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                System.out.println("itemStateChanged");
            }
        });
        combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("actionPerformed");
            }
        });
        combo.addItem("");
        combo.addItem("Long text 4");
        combo.addItem("Long text 3");
        combo.addItem("Long text 2");
        combo.addItem("Long text 1");
        combo.setEditable(true);
        JTextComponent tc = (JTextComponent) combo.getEditor().getEditorComponent();
        tc.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateLog(e, "inserted into");
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateLog(e, "inserted into");
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateLog(e, "inserted into");
            }

            public void updateLog(DocumentEvent e, String action) {
                Document doc = e.getDocument();
                int changeLength = e.getLength();
                System.out.println((changeLength + " character"
                        + ((changeLength == 1) ? " " : "s ")
                        + action + " " + doc.getProperty("name") + "."
                        + "  Text length = " + doc.getLength()));
            }
        });
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(combo);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class ComboToolTipRenderer extends BasicComboBoxRenderer {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private JComboBox combo;
        private JList comboList;

        ComboToolTipRenderer(JComboBox combo) {
            this.combo = combo;
        }

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
            System.out.println(value + ", " + index + ", " + isSelected + ", " + cellHasFocus);
            if (comboList == null) {
                comboList = list;
                KeyAdapter listener = new KeyAdapter() {

                    @Override
                    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("keyReleased " + e.getKeyCode());
                        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                            int x = 5;
                            int y = comboList.indexToLocation(comboList.getSelectedIndex()).y;
                            System.out.println("keyReleased " + comboList.getSelectedIndex());
                        }
                    }
                };
                combo.addKeyListener(listener);
                combo.getEditor().getEditorComponent().addKeyListener(listener);
                comboList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

                    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                        if (e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                            JList list = (JList) e.getSource();
                            int item = list.getSelectedIndex();
                            if (item > -1) {
                                String string = list.getSelectedValue().toString();
                                System.out.println("valueChanged " + list.getSelectedValue().toString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            if (isSelected) {
                System.out.println("isSelected " + value.toString());
            }
            return this;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ComboBoxHoverOver comboBoxHoverOver = new ComboBoxHoverOver();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your editor should be a `BasicComboBoxEditor`, you can then use its method  and use the method `addActionListener(yourListener);`